# How to get a list of tables that contain a specific column with a specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, information-schema

Tried searching this up myself but couldn’t find anything. If I’m looking for all tables that contain the column CarId and I’m only interested in Id 1, how can I get a list of all tables that match this criteria? This is using Transact SQL.

Comment: Please explain  "I’m only interested in Id 1". Is it the value of CardId column in the table? Is the db sql server?

Comment: I’m referring to the value under the CarId column, I’m only interested in this one row so if the CarId column does not have this value, don’t show the table name.

Comment: Answered as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using dynamic sql:

```sql
USE DATABASE_NAME -- your database name

--variables
DECLARE
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CRLF NVARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

--generate your sql
SELECT
    @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL, @CRLF)
        + 'SELECT '''
            + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLE_NAME '
        + 'FROM '
            + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
        + 'WHERE '
            + 'CarID = 1 ' + @CRLF
        + 'UNION '
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME = N'CarID'

--remove the last union
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 6)

--preview the generated sql
PRINT @SQL

--execute
--EXEC (@SQL)
```

Here we are using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to identify all tables containing the particular column you want.

Using that, we then generate a sql query to return only the table names where the `CarID = 1` is found, ignoring all other tables, or even the tables where you have this column, but not the id 1.

You can preview the query (on PRINT @SQL) and execute it separately, or you can uncomment EXEC (@SQL) to run all together.

Comment: Doesn’t this script require me to enter a table name? I’m trying to get the script to check for the value across all tables in the database so I don’t have a table name to enter though.

Comment: No, it doesn't require you to enter the table name, is checking in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for the given column name, and uses the TABLE_NAME found there. I will add more explanation in the answer.

Comment: This generates a script about 20 lines or so then gives me the error incorrect syntax near ‘=‘

Comment: It just means the generated script is longer than how much SSMS can print, and you're copying that straight away without checking the synstax (I think?). You can either use `SELECT @SQL` instead to get all script (enable retain CR/LF in SSMS results), or uncomment `EXEC (@SQL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Only List  TableNAmes

```
DECLARE  @ColumnName nvarchar(100) ='CarId'
DECLARE @ID int=2
create table #listTable (tableName varchar(100))
declare @sql nvarchar(max)= 'insert into #listTable SELECT  ''?'' FROM ? WHERE '+@ColumnName +'='''+cast(@ID as varchar(100))+''''
declare @whereand nvarchar(max)='AND O.ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM SYS.COLUMNS C WHERE C.NAME='''+@ColumnName+''')'
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1=@sql,@whereand=@whereand

select * from #listTable
```

all records

```
--USE [DataBase]
DECLARE  @ColumnName nvarchar(100) ='CarId'
DECLARE @ID int=2

declare @sql nvarchar(max)= ' SELECT * FROM ? WHERE '+@ColumnName +'='''+cast(@ID as varchar(100))+''''
declare @whereand nvarchar(max)='AND O.ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM SYS.COLUMNS C WHERE C.NAME='''+@ColumnName+''')'
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1=@sql,@whereand=@whereand
```

Comment: This runs the query for all tables with the column but it doesn’t check if the value exists. I was looking for a script that would check if it exist and return the table names without running all of them.

Comment: in the query first check exists column with   "  C WHERE C.NAME='''+@ColumnName+'''  " and check value with  '+@ColumnName +'='''+cast(@ID as varchar(100))+''''

Comment: Is your final result just the table name ? How did you know that it has a value of 1 without executing it?

Comment: I was hoping to get just the table names without executing each table, when you have a lot of tables it gets really cluttered.

Comment: I edited my code (Part 1:include table names with executing).if i will find a ways without executing ,I tell you

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  'select ' + quotename(t.[name],'''')+' as [table],* from ' + quoetname(t.name) + ' where CarID=1'
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id
where c.name='CarID'
```

run it, copy-paste the results into a new query window, run em

Comment: This won't necessarily provide a list, but good call on QUOTENAME. I got so used to NOT having to use it, that I forget there is always a chance is needed.

Comment: This provides a list of select statements but I would still have to run each one to see if the id exists.

Comment: @dizzyflames Indeed. On one hand, I recognise that falls a bit short as an answer. On the other, it should be fairly useful as a one-time run....which, hopefully, is what your case is.

Comment: @FAB I love `quotename`, and for those double and triple dynamic sqls I wish it weren't so limited on length.

Answer (score 0):

***Even you have cardid=1 for multiple rows table name will be selected once.

Sample Tables

```
-- Create first table
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    CardId INT
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (Id, Name, CardId)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 1),
    (2, 'Jane', 2),
    (3, 'Bob', 1);

-- Create second table
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Address VARCHAR(100),
    CardId INT
);

INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, Address, CardId)
VALUES
    (1, '123 Main St.', 2),
    (2, '456 Elm St.', 1),
    (3, '789 Oak St.', 3);

-- Create third table
CREATE TABLE Table3 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(50),
    Phone VARCHAR(20),
    CardId INT
);

INSERT INTO Table3 (Id, Email, Phone, CardId)
VALUES
    (1, 'john@example.com', '555-1234', 1),
    (2, 'jane@example.com', '555-5678', 2),
    (3, 'bob@example.com', '555-9012', 1);
```

Query:

```
enter code here
```

```
    DECLARE @SearchColumn NVARCHAR(255) = 'CardId';
    DECLARE @SearchValue INT = 1;
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
    SET @SQL = (
         SELECT top 1 string_agg('SELECT top 1''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TableName 
            FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + '
            WHERE ' + @SearchColumn + ' = ' + CAST(@SearchValue AS NVARCHAR(255)) + ' ',' union all ')
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @SearchColumn        
        
    );
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

| TableName |
| --- |
| Table1 |
| Table2 |
| Table3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RA1YRtgv)